# Master-Slave SSH Connection via Ruby "net/ssh" library and port forwarding

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I have ControlMaster enabled in my ssh config using

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ctrl-%h:%p
  ControlPersist 600
```

Next I connect to a remote host using

```
ssh remote-user@remote.com -p 4260
```

Now every 2nd connection to a particular host is routed to master connection without asking for password.

Now when I do port forwarding, like

```
ssh remote-user@remote.com -p 4260 -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

At this point I can access the mysql server running on host 'remote.com' & port '3306' via irb using

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(
:host => "127.0.0.1", 
:username => "db_user", 
:password => 'db_pass', 
:database => "db_name", 
:port => 3307
) 
client.query("select * from clients LIMIT 1").first
```

But I want to acheive port forwarding programatically, not via shell. So I tried using Net::SSH.start like this

```
Net::SSH.start("remote.com", "remote-user",{password: "remote-pass",port: 4260, :config => true, :forward_agent => true}) do |ssh|
  ssh.forward.local( 3307, '127.0.0.1', 3306 )
  ssh.loop
end
```

But this is creating a new SSH Connection and not using the master connection to connect to the server.

How do I perform both port forwarding and have ControlMaster connection at the same time using ruby Net::SSH?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? i have a similar problem trying to keep an ssh connection open with controlmaster.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to figure out a way to do this.